# View alpha not updating when animate

Tags: android, android-animation, alpha-transparency

I want to animate some view's alpha after drawing them on canvas.
Without animate, my code works.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    imgDot!!.alpha = 1f //initial value was 0f
    imgShadow!!.alpha = 1f
    ...
```

If I set view's alpha to 1f, it becomes visible as it should. But the problem is when I want to animate that view's alpha like in below, it doesn't work. Not only animation, but even it doesn't become visible.

```
imgShadow!!.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(1f)
```

Views are VISIBLE by default. I only change their alpha to zero at init.
I also tried to animate the view after onGlobalLayout(), but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I just realized my problem was due to onDraw() called repeatedly because of it's parent view redraws all its child views continuously and that's why animate() didn't have the time to animate the view.

Answer (score 0):

animate the view in onWindowFocusChanged function

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
             imgShadow!!.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(1f)
        }
}
```